# overflow : hidden does not work in Chrome

Tags: html, css, browser

I have a simple html as follow and I add style overflow: hidden to stop browser being scrolled and it works with all browsers except on windows version of chrome
Please help me?

```
<body style="background-color:yellow; overflow: hidden;">

<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
.
.
.
dddddddddddddddddddd
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Overflow hidden, should be working in all browsers. Set it on the body tag. Like:

```
<body style="overflow: hidden; position: fixed;">
Your content.
</body>
```

I tried this on Google Chrome and it works.

Comment: Beat me to it, this is is the way to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't set it on the body. You need to set a height on the element that you are limiting to hide any overflow. Here is an example http://jsfiddle.net/tP7qt/

```
<div style="background-color:yellow; overflow: hidden; height:150px;">
<br>
 more stuff below.  
 <br>
 <br>
 <br>
 <br>
 <br>
 <br>
 <br>
 <br>
 <br>
 <br>
 <br>
 <br>
 <br>
 <br>
 <br>
 <br>
 <br>
 <br>
 <br>
 <br>
 <br>
 <br>
 <br>
 <br>
 <br>
 <br>
 <br>
 <br>
 <br>
 <br>
 <br>
 <br>
 <br>
 <br>
 <br>
 <br>
 <br>
 <br>
 .
 .
 .
 Stuff here
 </div>
 </html>
```

Answer (score -1):

The actual problem with HTML elements is that the `overflow:hidden` property works only for elements with a **non-static** position.

So, set this on your body:

```
body {
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}
```